# How to change the opacity of the selected text?

Tags: css, selection, opacity

I have almost invisible text on the webpage with `opacity: 0.1;`
I want it to become visible when selected.

However, the selection is also almost invisible.
Unfortunately, `::selection` doesn't change the opacity.

Comment: Check out this link. http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

Comment: @Utkanos just tried to play with background color, opacity and ::selection

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't be able to use the `opacity` property with `::selection`. It was never one of the allowed properties, and even if it were implemented, it wouldn't make sense as you're not modifying the opacity of the element itself anyway.

You can use `rgba()` colors with the text and background rather than `opacity` on the entire element instead. It's not the ideal workaround, but it works at least for colors:

```css
body {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

::selection {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<p>Almost invisible text that turns opaque on selection.
```

Comment: Vow. Who would've thought about **allowed properties** with a particular selector! Great answer. Saves time one would have spent drowning in the W3C docs.

Comment: @Robin Maben: Yeah, that was something they experimented with when working on `::selection`. See this old revision of the CSS3 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-selectors-20051215/#UIfragments It has since been dropped, though, so it's no longer part of the standard. But now that you mention it, I wouldn't be surprised if there were only a limited set of properties that applied to other existing pseudo-elements like `::first-line` or `::first-letter` already as well, but I'm not too sure of that.

Comment: @Robin Maben: Also this probably has to do with the nature of *pseudo-elements*. Of course, it would never make sense to have only a set of allowed properties with any other selectors, since all they do are select elements. [Pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements) are different, in that they create new, virtual elements for styling purposes.

Comment: Yeah, it talks about dynamic (and virtual) elements created on-the-fly upon user interaction. I'm glad I learned something new. :)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using opacity, just set the alpha in the rgba color like so...

```
::selection {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)
}
```

Comment: why adding an answer that doesn't add anything to the accepted one which was posted 4 years before?